# What's the best option to download optional data for an Android app?

Tags: android

I have an app of 11 MB, and I'd like to download an asset of 61MB.

I used an Android expansion file, but the problem we found is that the size of the app is shown in the PlayStore as being 61MB, instead of just 11MB. This will discourage users from downloading.

Is there a way to use APK Expansion without downloading it at first, or do I need to host the optional asset on a S3 server or something?

Comment: The best way is to be honest with your users. Nobody wants to download an 11 MB app only to have it download an additional 61 MB of assets, especially on a tiered data plan. If the app is 61 MB and it is appealing to your users, they will download it, over wifi if they need to.

Comment: I'm not going to download the file without telling the user. I just need a good way to have the optional asset being downloaded only on-demand, when the user choose to.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have any idea how do it?

Comment: I had the same problem, did you fixed if so how ?